# Getting different AIC / BIC values for AR(2) estimation via AutoReg(2) vs ARIMA(2,0,0) through python statsmodels

Tags: time-series, python, arima, autoregressive, statsmodels

I am trying to fit an AR(2) model to a data series `claims_df['initial claims']` via `statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AutoReg` and `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA` to see if the results are inline. The estimated coefficients are inline but the `AIC` and `BIC` values are significantly different for a reason I can't understand. Also, the `log-likelihood` values are not very different in both models that might explain the difference in AIC / BIC values (sample size is same in both models) considering the formulas for AIC / BIC.

Can someone please explain the difference to me (and which one is correct)?

Below is the code and output snippets for your reference.

File link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gdV0rBUbGFNHLuAdo88TGx5r5-1s8YSx/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102682196277760308594&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg

claims_df = pd.read_excel('USUNINSCE.xlsx',
                          parse_dates = True,
                          index_col = 0)

# rename columns
claims_df.set_axis(['initial claims', 'dum rec'], axis = 'columns', inplace = True)

# AutoReg
mod = AutoReg(claims_df['initial claims'].values, lags = 2, old_names = False)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())

# ARIMA
arma_mod20 = ARIMA(claims_df['initial claims'].values, order = (2, 0, 0)).fit()
print(arma_mod20.summary())
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When `AutoReg` was first included in Statsmodels in e.g. v0.12, it used the AIC definition from Lutkepohl's book New Introduction to Time Series Analysis, which computes the AIC based on a version of the likelihood that excludes the constant term. This accounts for the very large difference you see here (+6 vs -771). In version 0.13 this was changed, so that if you upgrade Statsmodels, you will not see this large of a difference between the values.

**However** these two models are not the same: `AutoReg` uses least squares to estimate the parameters, and so the likelihood reported is from the conditional log-likelihood function (i.e. conditional on the initial datapoints). `SARIMAX` uses unconditional maximum likelihood estimation, and so it reports the unconditional log-likelihood.

So you shouldn't choose a model by comparing the AIC from a model estimated via `AutoReg` to one estimated using `SARIMAX`, even if the values look like they are of a similar magnitude.